# How to draw a circle around a point on a mapview?

Tags: android

How could I draw a circle surrounding a point on the map with a certain radius? this radius must be of for example 1KM and must stay 1KM on the map at all times (will get smaller when zoomed out and so on).

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to draw a circle on the map. You can do this by calculating points that make up the points. The following code takes in a *VELatLong* for the center point and a radius in kilometers. It returns a *VEShapeType.Polygon* object. You can then add this shape to the map using `map.AddShape()`.

Code Snippet:

```
function AddCircle(latlong, radius)
{
    var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
    var lat = (latlong.Latitude * Math.PI) / 180; //rad
    var lon = (latlong.Longitude * Math.PI) / 180; //rad
    var d = parseFloat(radius)/R;  // d = angular distance covered on earth's surface
    var points= new Array();
    for (x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
    {
        var p2 = new VELatLong(0,0)           
        brng = x * Math.PI / 180; //rad
        p2.Latitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat)*Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat)*Math.sin(d)*Math.cos(brng));
        p2.Longitude = ((lon + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d)*Math.cos(lat), Math.cos(d)-Math.sin(lat)*Math.sin(p2.Latitude))) * 180) / Math.PI;
        p2.Latitude = (p2.Latitude * 180) / Math.PI;
        points.push(p2);
    }
    var poly = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Polyline, points);
    return poly;
}
```